# Disable Firefox auto-search when using keypress() in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

**Question:**

I am running a function where you press the keys C or M using the keypress() function and every time I press one of those keys, the letter is marked automatically in Firefox. Is there a way to disable this using JavaScript or is this something Firefox does by default?

I have tried to look for an answer using Google but it seems no one has had this issue before using the keypress() function in JS.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var once = false;
        $(window).keypress(function(e)
        {
            if(!once)
            {
                if (e.which == 99)
                {
                    once = true;
                    $("input#left").val( 1 );
                    $("form").submit();
                }
                else if (e.which == 109)
                {
                    once = true;
                    $("input#right").val( 1 );
                    $("form").submit();
                }
            }
        });                 
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: May be you need use autocomplete="off" in your input

Answer (score 2):

Just call preventDefault():

```
$(window).keypress(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault()
    // other code
}
```

Comment: Disables every key event. F5 and other shortcuts don't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of handling this. If you call `e.preventDefault()` you should be covered, however that's not your only option.

HTML5 introduced many new tags and attributes into markup, one of them being an `autocomplete` attribute for text fields. If you add this to your HTML (`<input type='text' id='myInput' autocomplete='off'>`) you should be covered as well. You can't always rely on your user having support for HTML5, but this is still an easy solution to your problem.

It can't hurt you to implement both of these small changes in your code.